# Ampersand after function declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

I came across this piece of code recently

```
T operator () () &
{
...
}

T operator () () &&
{
...
}
```

and I'm confused. What do the & and && mean in this context? Is this similar to a copy & move constructor but for functions?

Comment: Voting to close, but +1, because this question has good search terms.

Comment: Another good link: [RValue references and Move Semantics](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html)

Comment: I changed your tag. It's a C++11 feature.